Rendering Quarto document with multiple gt tables printed via purrr::map
I’m encountering an issue with rendering tables in my Quarto Markdown document. I’m using walk and map to generate tables with a custom function, but instead of displaying the tables, only the HTML code of the tables is printed.
Here is a reproducible example of my code:
---
title: "Table Rendering Issue"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
# Creating a sample dataset
ds_sep <- data.frame(
  column_name = c("02", "02", "01"),
  var1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 3)
)

# List of variables of interest
var_sociodemo <- c("var1", "var2")

# Custom function to create tables
table_sociodemo <- function(data, column, value) {
  data %>%
    filter(!!sym(column) == value) %>%
    gt()
}

# Generating and printing the tables
walk(map(var_sociodemo, ~table_sociodemo(ds_sep, "column_name", .x)), print)
```

I expect the tables to be displayed correctly in the document.
Instead of the tables, I get only the HTML code, as shown below:

How can I ensure that the tables are rendered correctly in the Quarto Markdown document instead of just getting the HTML code? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Just use ```{r results='asis'}

Figuring out how to render multiple tables from a loop in Quarto is the most important question on the internet. It is soooo mind-bogglingly impossible to do for some reason. It doesn't help that errors from rendering a Quarto document are indecipherable.

I've done something similar (printing a gt inside a function that also prints plots, for RMarkdown), by using as_raw_html() and then cat(). E.g.:
ff <- function(species) {
    gt(iris) %>%
    filter(Species == species) %>%
    as_raw_html() %>%
    cat()
}


I tried but it still doesn't work. I've tried with iris' data and the output is the same. I'm working on Quarto, could be that the problem?

I don't have experience with Quarto. In RMarkdown I have to set the output of the code chunk to "asis" ({r results = "asis"}), for it to be properly interpreted as raw HTML, otherwise it gets formatted and printed as code. Maybe there is a similar option in Quarto.

Now, it prints the table in latex format but it prints one column for each row

I am trying to render a quorto pdf and was having similar issues.
This is what worked for me. The sig_groups function takes two arguments and here I am iterating the var_names argument. Adding space before and after every table helped the latex to render the code correctly. Hope this helps!
var_names <- c("age_group", "father_edu", "family_home")

walk(var_names, function(var) {
  cat("\n\n")
  print(sig_groups(df, var, "cogCNI"))
  cat("\n\n")
})


Do you know which library the function come from? On google I've just foud this source: https://iobr.github.io/IOBR/IOBR-VIGNETTE.html
